# Difference between the ifeq directive and the if function in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, flow-control

What is the difference between an `ifeq` directive in GNU Make and the `if` function?
When should I use each? Are they different because `ifeq` is parsed by a "pre-processor" in GNU Make?

Comment: `ifeq` is a Make conditional, `if` is not. Commands in rules are in shell language, so `if` might appear there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` function is for [conditional expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html).  The `ifeq` function and other regular [conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html) has no guarantee that the parts will not be expanded if they are not true.  Check out the links (in particular the first one) for a bit of elaboration.

Comment: By golly... Conditional expansion... +1